# Show the mean arrow on a circular plot

Tags: r, plot

I plot my phenological data (Fejeuncirculangle) with library circular. I obtain a conventional graphic but it's impossible for me to show the mean arrow in this plot. I don't understand why because I can easily add the arrows for each of the initial values, segments and text for the months in the plot. Below is my code. Is it a problem with the code?

```
x11()
plot.new()
library(circular)
na.exclude(tinitialcirculangle)
plot(tinitialcirculangle$Fejeuncirculangle,pch=20,col="blue",stack=TRUE,shrink=1.2,bins=52,ticks=TRUE)
Fejeuncirculangle<-circular(tinitialcirculangle$Fejeuncirculangle,type="angles",units="degrees",template="none",zero=circular(pi/2),rotation="clock",names="Feuiljeuncirculangle")
par(mai=c(0.5,0.75,0.5,0.75),cex.axis=1,cex.lab=1)
rose.diag(Fejeuncirculangle,bins=52,main="",col="darkolivegreen1",axes=FALSE)
points(Fejeuncirculangle,pch=20,col="darkolivegreen1",bg="black",next.points=+0.05)
arrows.circular(Fejeuncirculangle)
arrows.circular(mean(Fejeuncirculangle),angle=15,length=0.20,lwd=5,col="black")

# Month Segments - Ajouter les segments de séparation des mois
segments(0,0,1,0,col="black",lty=3,lwd=1)
segments(0,0,sqrt(3)/2,0.5,col="black",lty=3,lwd=1)
segments(0,0,0.5,sqrt(3)/2,col="black",lty=3,lwd=1)
segments(0,0,0,1,col="black",lty=3,lwd=1)
segments(0,0,-0.5,sqrt(3)/2,col="black",lty=3,lwd=1)
segments(0,0,-sqrt(3)/2,0.5,col="black",lty=3,lwd=1)
segments(0,0,-1,0,col="black",lty=3,lwd=1)
segments(0,0,-sqrt(3)/2,-0.5,col="black",lty=3,lwd=1)
segments(0,0,-0.5,-sqrt(3)/2,col="black",lty=3,lwd=1)
segments(0,0,0,-1,col="black",lty=3,lwd=1)
segments(0,0,0.5,-sqrt(3)/2,col="black",lty=3,lwd=1)
segments(0,0,sqrt(3)/2,-0.5,col="black",lty=3,lwd=1)

# Month texts - Ajouter les mois au graphique circulaire
text(0.2329,0.8693,"J",family="Calibri",font=1,cex=1)
text(0.6363,0.6363,"F",family="Calibri",font=1,cex=1)
text(0.8693,0.2329,"M",family="Calibri",font=1,cex=1)
text(0.8693,-0.2329,"A",family="Calibri",font=1,cex=1)
text(0.6363,-0.6363,"M",family="Calibri",font=1,cex=1)
text(0.2329,-0.8693,"J",family="Calibri",font=1,cex=1)
text(-0.2329,-0.8693,"J",family="Calibri",font=1,cex=1)
text(-0.6363,-0.6363,"A",family="Calibri",font=1,cex=1)
text(-0.8693,-0.2329,"S",family="Calibri",font=1,cex=1)
text(-0.8693,0.2329,"O",family="Calibri",font=1,cex=1)
text(-0.6363,0.6363,"N",family="Calibri",font=1,cex=1)
text(-0.2329,0.8693,"D",family="Calibri",font=1,cex=1)
```

Comment: In fact mean(Fejeuncirculangle) return NA. But my values is in a numeric format (is.numeric return TRUE) and I don't understand why is not possible to have the mean.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
arrows.circular(mean(Fejeuncirculangle,na.rm=TRUE),angle=15,length=0.20,lwd=5,col="black")
```

If that works it's because you haven't excluded NA values, I suspect that your fourth line should be:

```
tinitialcirculangle <- na.exclude(tinitialcirculangle)
```